# How to set title for cocos2dx newest version

Tags: c++, visual-studio, game-engine, game-development

I've gotten started with Cocos2dx last week and I've been trying to set a title for the window of game. I modified "CCEGLWievProtocol.h" file and I changed the privacy of `m_szViewName` variable to `public`... and finally I changed my main function in this way:

```
    AppDelegate app;
    CCEGLView* eglView = CCEGLView::sharedOpenGLView();
    strcpy(eglView->m_szViewName, "test");
    eglView->setFrameSize(1000, 540);
    int ret = CCApplication::sharedApplication()->run();
```

But it doesn't work and the title hasn't been changed! What should I do?
Do you suggest any better cross-plattform C++ game engines instead Cocos2dx?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried the same thing but it did not work but then 
As it is windows

we can do it using windows handle

```
HWND _handle= eglView->getHWnd();
SetWindowText(_handle, "Title");
```